# how do i make content load at the top of the page except all the way at the bottom

Tags: html, css

So I started a 1st new page in `HTML` and I added an `image` and when I add a text or just anything on the page it loads all the way at the bottom of the page even though I set the `overflow: hidden` and then I have to set the `bottom px` higher in `CSS` just to get them back to the top where I want my content at am doing something wrong or what and also every time I add the pixels higher or just even 1 and back to the live server to see the page, the whole page goes down all I see is just white space please how do I fix this?

**`HTML`**

```
<body> 
    <img class="image1" src="image1.jpg"> 
    <div class="square" id="hello"></div> 
    <p class="welcome1">welcome page</p>
```

**`CSS`**

```
body{ 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
} 
.square#hello{ 
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 339px; 
    width:1030px; 
    height:265px; 
    background-color: white; 
    margin-left: 118px; 
    border-radius: 2px; 
} 
.welcome1{ 
    position:relative; 
    bottom:620px; 
    margin-left: 220px; 
    font-size:100px; 
    font-family: "bangers"; 
    color: blue; 
}
```

Comment: What? I don't understand the question. `position:absolute; bottom:0;`???

Comment: okay look, so say i start a new fresh page called index.html and do all the doctype stuff so in the body tags say i want to add a image on the page so once i add it it displays all the way at the bottom of the page so now i have to keep making the bottom px higher to get back up to the page where i want the image so when i keep adding content they load at the very bottom but i want them to display at the top even if the overflows x and y are hidden it still happens

Comment: so i want to be moving things around and putting them where i like on the page so therefor do i use absolute or relative or what ?